# Normal Map weirdness!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, normal-map

[image]Newbie Blender artist here and I'm having some issue with a Normal Map. The Map seems smooth but when rendered it seems to show some weird topology rather than smooth surfaces. If anyone could help me with this I would be eternally grateful.

[image: Zoom in for weird artefacts]

Blender file - https://we.tl/t-Of5E9bSkW2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the viewport, render properties and node setup's screenshot for better understanding of your problem?

Comment: Could you round the weird topology that you are referring to. Do you mean the top right bump? Also please supply the blend file. I'll look into it.

Comment: .blend file added to question. It's not just the bump in the top right, if you zoom in you can see lots of lines like on a map. This should be smooth.

Comment: That's probably because of image compression happening after wrongly used node setup. Normal Map node should be plugged into blue Normal input sockets of shaders (Diffuse, Glossy, Principled etc), and image texture should be set to Non-Color.

Comment: @Mr Zak - Thanks that was the issue! Thanks to everyone else too.